# Bash - Add blank line above line starting with a period

Tags: linux, bash

I need to edit a text file by adding a blank line *above* every line starting with a period.

Before

```
Corn
.Apple
Words.
.Orange
Bean
```

After

```
Corn

.Apple
Words.

.Orange
Bean
```

Here is what I have so far.
This adds a spaces after every period. There are more in the actual file.

```
cat File.txt | sed -r 's/([.]+)/\n\1/g'
```

This displays the lines that start with a period

```
while read -r line; do

if [[ "$line" == "."* ]]; then

echo "$line"

fi

done < File.txt
```

How do I merge them together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces the output that you want:

```
$ sed 's/^[.]/\n./' file
Corn

.Apple
Words.

.Orange
Bean
```

If you want to change the file in-place, use sed's `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/^[.]/\n./' file
```

For Mac OSX or other BSD system, use:

```
sed -i '' 's/^[.]/\n./' file
```

We use `^` which matches only at the beginning of a line.  Since we are matching a period at the beginning of the line, it is not necessary to capture a group with parentheses: we know the match is  a period.  All that we need to do is add a newline before that period.

Answer (score 1):

with sed

```
sed 's/^\./\n\./'
```

with awk

```
awk '/^\./{print ""} 1'
```

or

```
awk 'sub(/^\./,"\n.") 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using RegExp it could be:

```
cat File.txt | sed -r 's/^(\..+)/\n\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an awk script is going to work best.

```
/^\./ {print "";}
{print $0;}
```

Put that into a file, in this case, called "awkfile" and run it like `awk -f awkfile File.txt'

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -e '/^\./i\\' pru.txt  
Corn

.Apple
Words.

.Orange
Bean
```

this command line instructs `sed(1)` to search for lines beginning with a dot, and then insert a blank line before it.  Look in `sed(1)` manual page for how to use the `i`nsert, `r`eplace and `a`ppend commands.